# How to encrypt web.config with no access to server and no key exchange

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, encryption, entity

I'm working on my first .net project using .net 4, mvc4 and entity framework. The project is an api for an iOS application.

Unfortunately one of the requirements is that the project be delivered in a zip file with the connection strings pre-encrypted. This would be straight forward using aspnet_regiis except that I have no access to the server, am not allowed to do key exchange and encrypt on first run is also unacceptable to the client. I can however package any dlls I like in the app.

I have pointed out to the client that this only gives the illusion of security since I will have to pack the decrypt code in the app, to no avail.

So now I am trying to figure out how to pre-encrypt the connection strings in web.config in the simplest most straight forward manner. I've searched both here and via google and while I believe that I will need to create a custom provider and encrypt with aspnet_regiis I would really appreciate guidance from the community.

Comment: Not sure what ols means, but here's a link to a gist with my current connect section https://gist.github.com/philpeterman/5909061 (the section is too long to paste here)

Comment: and what I need to end up with should look similar to this: 

<connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="TripleDESProvider"> <EncryptedData>FPfvfMRROoZGLIht3ozZsw0/H50h4mX9Ulu4VWuN1CGNl/uJTBBO8FogMvtVjpvvL‌​I9rIOLmNotLneHTFMyZFrsHmFpTCyvwpm45gFFIsQOtlYs5dltNUpHeap9zX6t4Vtgmm1pw+sG3SN6f0K‌​f9GqTWlRUq7VXy4CzklWtwoIukWjRDSWUuK6k/4pljrTC5Ia5iOy73D2CI6V02+M0O+V44XXZM+b1Omnc‌​....SKTrS8qn8Fb0ZO3smt8wP5vPGBv+1qVfoOEl7OBOV+gnc6Kdp2RDiS9/aOi5W4/OD39/oiwRjHyA==</E‌​ncryptedData> </connectionStrings>

Comment: No worries, just wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

Comment: Please have your managers read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: Excellent article, unfortunately the client is not interested in changing their requirements. I've had several conversations with them re the illusion of security vs actual security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally puzzled this out. This may not be the best answer to the problem but it worked just fine.

The key was indeed building a custom protected configuration provider. Following the steps from MS found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33ws57y0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Once I had that in place I encrypted the connection strings section of the web.config using aspnet_regiis. This gave me the cypher text that the client required.

The hardest part was figuring out the correct path for keyFilePath=

Once I had that I packaged the Keys.txt file with the application (remember to choose copy always in the files properties in the solution explorer). Added the reference to my custom provider (again copy always in the references section of solution explorer) and Bob's your uncle.

Hope this helps someone else.